# Is a dimension or fact table more appropriate for this scenario?

Tags: data-modeling, dimensional-modeling

I'm struggling as to whether I should have this data live as a fact or dimension table, and would like some help.

In general terms, the data and business process is a customer's/accountholder's billing activity (customer = accountholder). Most customers get billed on a monthly basis. The raw source data lives at the granularity of a row = customer. So when a customer's account information gets updated, their record is updated, instead of creating a new row.

There are quite a few measures that make me want to say I should create a fact table. These include `bill_total`, `bill_amount_reamining` and `notice_amount`. But since the source data is only updated as opposed to creating a new row, I'm getting tripped up as to how to declare the granularity of this new fact (or maybe dim) table.

Also important that I mention that I want to track the history, not just the most recent data. So is it acceptable to have fields like `effective_date` and `end_date` on a fact table? Or if I want fields like that, should I be creating a dimension table?

Hopefully that provides enough context, happy to add more details if needed.

Comment: What language? Please use the relevant tag.

Answer (score 0):

The customer's account information belongs in a dimension and, if you want to keep history, then it needs to be an SCD (slowly changing dimension).

Measures such as bill_total, bill_amount_remaining and notice_amount belong in a fact table, with FKs to the relevant dimensions - such as your Account Dim, Date Dim, etc